# parse value from previous activity and display on current activity spinner field in android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

i have developed one app.here i have to parse the value from one activity to next activity.the parse value is display on textview means successfully displayed.but the parse value is displayed on spinner means the value is not display in this app.

this is my code:

```
public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";

private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;

static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("status"));


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in = getIntent();
             String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
             String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

            request.addProperty(unameProp);
            PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
            idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
            idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(idProp);



              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try{
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  result.setText(response.toString());
             }
           catch(Exception e){

           }
              }
    });

    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

}

//Add animals into spinner dynamically
private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}






public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

       }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Here the status is parsed from pervious activity and display on current activity using TextView means its worked well...but i wish to need the parsed value is display on spinner.how can i manage the above code.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have used below code.it is work for me.

```
 Intent in = getIntent();
    String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(status);
```

Yes i have to add the status in list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the dropdown list.
If the parsed value is new item, you have to add to the list and notify the adapter.
If the parsed value is existing value, you can find the item position in list and set the spinner selected item position.

```
// to set the spinner selected item
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Spinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
Spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertionExample.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);;
}});
```